# Which Google API version to use for Android Project in order to use Google Maps

Tags: android

I am new to Android and trying to develop an application which uses Google Maps.
I am currently using Google APIs8 (Android 2.2), but I am having some errors in my project as below-
res/layout/categories.xml
line -

> ScrollView  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"

error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'scrollbarFadeDuration' in package 'android'

Please Help!!
Thanks,
Deepali

Answer (score 0):

You are using correct version,I also did it with same sdk.
Here is the link for google map integration.

And if you are using eclipse while generating kestore make sure to mention extention as "projectName.kestore" not just "projectName".